# Warcraft 3 Editor - Export Changes

Tags: warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

So I changed a map with custom units and options, is there any way to export the changes and import it to another map?

Comment: Consider asking this question on gamedev.stackexchange instead. You may have better luck there, and such questions are explicitly part of their scope.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer I think it sits between the cracks of gaming and gamedev enough that someone has to step up to answer it. It's practically died already.

Comment: @Sadly Not (Wow, your name is relevant) See this meta thread here: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here

Comment: In that case, migrate?

Answer (score 2):

The Warcraft 3 Editor uses campaigns to share data between multiple maps. In your case simply create a campaign and then import all data (units, triggers, whatever) from the map into the campaign. Then, if you add any other maps to the same campaign you can export data from the campaign out to your other maps.

The only trick to this is that importing and exporting *copies* data; changes you make in one place will not be reflected in others. So be careful to update your changes in all maps and the campaign if you want to be consistent! The best practice is to make changes to the campaign and then push the changes to your maps: that way you know that the campaign always contains the most up-to-date data.